# Question about move-aware container and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, move, unique-ptr

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which says that:

> std::unique_ptr is commonly used to manage the lifetime of objects, including:
> **as the element type in move-aware containers, such as std::vector**,
> **which hold pointers to dynamically-allocated objects** (e.g. if
> polymorphic behavior is desired) [emphasis mine]

How to understand it in the right way?

Some simple example may helps.

Thanks.

Comment: It just means `std::vector` moves instead of copies its elements when possible, which is required for `std::unique_ptr` because it's not copyable.

Comment: If you've ever filled a vector with raw pointers that you then have to delete later, you'll understand the benefits of filling it with `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: This statement refers to the deprecated `std::auto_ptr`, that was not safe to use in the containers.

Comment: @PasserBy As far as I can see, I have to **explicitly** invoking std::vector::push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>&&) other than std::vector::push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>&), i.e. [vec.push_back(std::move(foo_unique_ptr)) other than vec.push_back(foo_unique_ptr)](https://godbolt.org/z/h7aY5ab9o) , am I right?

Comment: Yes, you have to explicitly move something that's owned elsewhere (in this case on the stack).  After the move, the stack object is valid but in an undefined state -- you may not use it.  The vector now owns the unique pointer.  This entirely encapsulates the concept of _unique_ -- only one thing can own it.  See a toy example of how unique_ptr simplifies memory management in a vector of pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/csrPEnxbd

Comment: @paddy Very good example to learn. Thank you so much. My understanding of this matter is at a different level with your help.

Answer (score 0):

This statement refers to the fact that it was notoriously unsafe to use `std::auto_ptr` as an element in containers. `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated already since C++11, but before that there was no move semantics in C++, and `auto_ptr` was the only "smart" pointer that was really standartized.

`std::auto_ptr` was similar to `std::unique_ptr` in that it was destroying the underlying object in the destructor. In contrast to the unique pointer, auto pointer allowed copying: the ownership of the object was transferring to the destination, while the source object was losing the ownership, still pointing to the object. This behavior was unsafe in containers: while you may rely on that the container of auto pointers keeps the ownership, you may easily lose it by simple access to the element (imagine what would happen when you would access the element next time after the actual temporary owner would be destroyed).

It worth mentioning that the STL library provided by Visual Studio C++ 6.0 had a different implementation of `auto_ptr`: instead of transferring the ownership this "smart" pointer was transferring everything, even the pointer value itself. That meant that the source `auto_ptr` was becoming empty after the assignment to another "copy" of this pointer. That was safer to store the objects like that in a container, but it caused other problems anyway.

Overall, the problems with usage `auto_ptr` in containers was [probably] the main reasons why `std::auto_ptr` was deprecated in C++11.

Returning back to `std::unique_ptr`: it is safe to use it in containers, and the standard clearly makes an explicit statement referring to the previous problems with `std::auto_ptr`.